# Ionic Globally Call IonViewWillEnter on App.component.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello im trying to call globaly function on all view page, its possible on ionic ?
im add ionViewWillEnter on app.component.ts still not working

> ionViewWillEnter(){
> console.log('aaa');   }

thankyou

Comment: its because your `app.component.ts` is not in your life cycle hook. these functions only works on your views/pages. Can you explain why are you using this in `app.component`

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts has no view so you can't use ionViewWillEnter(). You can use ngOnInit.

this can also help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420241/angular-2-global-lifecycle-hooks`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution you can consider for your project. I use `NavigationStart` and `NavigationEnd` events in Router instead of `ionViewWillEnter` and `ionViewDidEnter`.

Please review [Ionic Page Life Cycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle):
Begin Navigation -> ngOnInit -> Begin page transition -> ionViewWillEnter -> Page fully transitioned.

**app.components.ts**

```js
import {
  Router,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  Event as NavigationEvent,
} from "@angular/router";

class Example {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.initGlobalRouteEvent();
  }

  initGlobalRouteEvent() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log("ionViewWillEnter app-root \n");
        return;
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log("ionViewDidEnter app-root \n");
      }
    });
  }
}
```